# Which DLC I need to concentrate development in EU4?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I've seen in many youtube videos (e.g. [this](https://youtu.be/xci_753xpvY?t=600)) that in the state view there is a button to concentrate development and make coring provinces cheaper. However, I cannot find that button when I play EU4. Which DLC do I need to enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the latest big one - Leviathan. Here's the wiki page that lists all dlc and features they unlock

https://eu4.paradoxwikis.com/Downloadable_content

Also notice that you lose some portion of development. It's not just free cheaper cores. And the upcoming free patch is going to nerf that ability significantly